# I'm working on a project, and I want to see how it ran in its last revision. How do I do it without losing my changes?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar

Specifically, I'm using bzr, but tips for any VCS are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are three options.

1. Use [shelving](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/development/en/user-guide/shelving_changes.html)

   `bzr shelve --all`
   `bzr unshelve`
2. Create a separate branch with the
   latest
3. Create a patch of you
   changes and revert the changes.
   Apply patch when you need your
   changes back.

Comment: You may want to use `bzr shelve --all` if you don't want to go through usual interactive selection process.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Git](http://git-scm.com):

```
git checkout HEAD^    # get the previous version, changing files on disk to match
make                  # run your project (or whatever command you use)
git checkout master   # return to the "master" branch
```

The above applies if you've already committed whatever current changes you're working on, and want to go back to the *previous* commit. If you have changes that have *not* been committed yet, then use the [stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

```
git stash             # save the uncommitted changes away
make                  # ...
git stash pop         # restore your uncommitted changes
```

You can make and commit other changes in between the stash and the pop; this is Git's solution to the "boss interrupts with an immediate bug fix request" problem.